# Java Web Service Client Timeout values not changing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, timeout

is there  a reason when I set the time out for a service call from the client that it doesnt override the defualt values?

I have tried all these but no luck.

```
DictionaryTransferService service = new DictionaryTransferService();

DictionaryTransfer port = service.getDictionaryTransferPort();

((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, 10 * 60 * 1000);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", 5 * 60 * 1000);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 10 * 60 * 1000);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants for these JAX-WS RI settings changed at one point, so it may be that you need to use these instead:

```
"com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout"
"com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout"
```

Or better yet, use the constants from the `JAXWSProperties` class itself.

You might also try these since you're running JBoss:

```
org.jboss.ws.core.StubExt.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
org.jboss.ws.core.StubExt.PROPERTY_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT
```